# WooCommerce: How to disable variable_product_type_options in my plugin?

Tags: performance, woocommerce, hook, product-variations

I want to disable the call to variable_product_type_options in my plugin. The plugin is a little helper function, that will help the user to create custom variations, instead of going through the regular variations in the default form. I want to do this, because a product has very long loading and saving times when it has too many variations (say, for example 100). Also, nobody really wants to edit these manually. Anyway, they are loaded by default for a product of type "variable", so I want to remove this.

I know, all I have to do is this:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_product_write_panels', 'variable_product_type_options');
```

The only problem is, that I can't find the right place to do that. I have tried in the action "woocommerce_loaded" but it's still there. So I need to know which WooCommerce action will be fired after the woocommerce_product_write_panels but before the admin form for the product is processed.

Comment: I just see, the new version of WooCommerce has removed this action hook entirely. So I assume I now have no chance to remove it.

Comment: I wanted also to use this hook to show some custom field on a custom tab, but with no chance. Until I find the solution I am needed to use the general tab hook 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data'. Pity enough from Woo by not specifying an alternative solution.